# The class sylius.model.product_archetype.class does not exist.

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am working on a Symfony 2 app and in the process of integrating the Sylius product bundle I get the following error when running

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

The error is

```
 The class sylius.model.product_archetype.class does not exist.
```

**Configuration**
This is my confi.yml file

```
    sylius_cart:
    resolver: app.cart_item_resolver # The id of our newly created service.
    classes: ~ # This key can be empty but it must be present in the configuration.

sylius_order:
    driver: doctrine/orm # Configure the doctrine orm driver used in documentation.

sylius_money: ~

sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
            timestampable: true

#sylius_archetype:
sylius_archetype:
    driver: doctrine/orm # Configure the doctrine orm driver used in the documentation.

sylius_translation:
  default_locale: en
```

And the bundles I have include are 
new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),

```
   new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
    new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
    new WhiteOctober\PagerfantaBundle\WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\SyliusProductBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\AttributeBundle\SyliusAttributeBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\VariationBundle\SyliusVariationBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\TranslationBundle\SyliusTranslationBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\SyliusCartBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\OrderBundle\SyliusOrderBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\MoneyBundle\SyliusMoneyBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\ArchetypeBundle\SyliusArchetypeBundle(),
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here. It seems that the docs does not match the code any more.

Answer (score 0):

The core team is working hard to cleanup the documentation ([see here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/5275)), aiming to the 1.0 beta release.

It seems you require a lot of components from Sylius. What about starting from the standard edition and create you own bundle to change whatever you want ? The customization guide is freshly up to date ([here](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/index.html)).

Comment: yes documentation is actually a mess. I would be great if it can specify the version it is intended for. I have already my app build and going back will be to much delay. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Core config reference for product archetype is the following:

```
sylius_archetype:
resources:
    product:
        archetype:
            classes:
                model: Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Archetype
                interface: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ArchetypeInterface
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ArchetypeTranslation
                    interface: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ArchetypeTranslationInterface
        subject: Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product
        attribute: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Attribute
        option: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Option
```

You have to change, I guess

```
Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Archetype
```

by

```
Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Archetype
```

And

```
Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product
```

by

```
Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I ended up moving to the sonata e-commerce bundle